# Count errors in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to count correctly errors in Wordpress?

So far I tried this:

```
if(count( $errors )==0) echo 'no errors'; else 'some errors';
```

but this is not working, it display everytime: some errors.

I did `var_dump($errors):`

```
object(WP_Error)#180 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(0) { } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Please tell me how to do this correctly, to count errors.

empty( $errors ) returns false

Comment: did you try `isset($errors[0]) ` or `is_empty( $errors )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing things by creating a `WP_Error` object called `$errors` that itself has a property called `$errors`. What do you get if you use:

```
if(count( $errors->errors )==0) echo 'no errors'; else echo 'some errors';
```

I think you're calling `count` on a WP_Error object rather than its $errors array property. When you `count` an *object* in PHP, according [to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

> If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

I'm guessing that WP_Error is an object without an implemented Countable interface, so you'll always get the value 1 back if you `count()` one.